# CSS file is not linking to my HTML file

Tags: html, css

I feel like I'm just overlooking something very simple. I cannot get my CSS file for my sort menu to link to my html file.The relevant code is below.

It should be noted that the CSS file is in `CSS/home/sortmenu.css`.

`link` Code:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/all/page.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/all/header.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/all/mainmenu.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/home/table.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/home/sortmenu.css">
</head>
```

CSS Code:

```
/*
#sortmenu {
position: absolute;
background-color: #333;
border: 5px solid #222;
border-top: 0;
margin-left: -5px;
width: 160px;
}
#sortmenu > li {
display: block;
position: relative;
}
#sortmenu li a:hover {
color: #699;
}
#sortmenu li: hover ul {
display: inline-block;
}

.sortsubmenu {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #333;
border: 5px solid #222;
border-left: 0px;
text-align: right;
top: -5px;
left: 100%;
width: auto;
}

.sortsubmenu li{
display: inline;
white-space: nowrap;
}

.sortsubmenu li a:hover {
color: #DB7093;
}

#songsortmenu {
border-top: 0px;
}
*/

#sortmenu {
background-color: #222;
}

#sortmenu_wrapper {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
}

#sortmenu ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the console for any errors. So 404 error if you're looking for files in the wrong place.

Comment: Show a screen shot of your project structure.

Comment: like the folder directories?

Comment: It appears that it IS linking correctly, as I was able to change something unrelated to the sortmenu I am trying to create, so it must be a problem with how I am referring to the menu...but I'm still unsure what I'm doing wrong there.

Comment: Clear your cache and hard refresh, that may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove `/` before `div`

```
<div id="sortmenu">
    <div id="sortmenu_wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>Name</a></li><li>
            <a href='#'>Artist</a></li><li>
            <a href='#'>Album</a></li><li>
            <a href='#'>Genre</a></li><li>
            <a href='#'>Release Date</a></li><li>
            <a href='#'>BPM</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the path to `css` file is `CSS/home/sortmenu.css` like below.

```
Project ROOT
|-- currentFile.php
`-- CSS
    `-- home
        `-- sortmenu.css
```

then you should use.

**`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/home/sortmenu.css">`**

**NOT**

<strike>**`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/home/sortmenu.css">`**</strike>

Comment: that wasn't it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in css path settings. Checkout this page. You'll definitely find the answer.

https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/